# Spring-boot is not recognising Koltin serializers written for third party libraries

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, serialization, arrows, kotlinx.serialization

The external class I am using: https://github.com/arrow-kt/arrow/blob/5e0db6b7aaeb1ac99ecbfff74f03cce28e234391/arrow-libs/core/arrow-core/src/commonMain/kotlin/arrow/core/Either.kt#L725

Either Sealed class from Arrow.Core library.

This is my custom serializer for Either

```
@Serializer(forClass = arrow.core.Either::class)
object EitherSerializer : KSerializer<Either<ErrorResponse, SuccessResponse>> {
```

With this setup, I am expecting Springboot to use Kotlin serializer instead of jackson2. own class Kotlin serializers(using @Serializable) is recognized by the Kotlin runtime and it's using KotlinSerializationJsonHttpMessageConverter but in the above case, (using @Serialzer) default Jackson HTTP message converter is invoked.

Comment: I am able to manually serialize/deserialize using the usual methods
`Json.encodeToString(EitherSerializer, response)`.  The problem is only when Either is being used as an API Response

Comment: What version of Spring boot do you use?

Comment: See https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlinx-serialization-with-spring-boot/16540/11 and https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlinx-serialization-with-spring-boot/16540/15

Comment: I am using spring boot 2.6.0-Snapshot  depedencies